# How to run a function on theme activation only in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add a capability to one of the default roles in WordPress. The [add_cap article](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_cap) advises people to do this sort of thing on theme activation because the setting is saved to the database:

> NB: This setting is saved to the database, so it might be better to run this on theme/plugin activation

The function I intend to use is:

```
function add_theme_caps() {
    $role = get_role( 'author' );
    $role->add_cap( 'edit_others_posts' ); 
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_theme_caps');
```

As you can see, I'm currently hooking to `admin_init`, which causes the function to be run each time the admin area is accessed. How can I run the function on theme activation only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `after_switch_theme` . It will affect only your theme, of course.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/after_switch_theme

Answer (score 0):

I feel you should try something like this

```
if ( is_admin() && isset($_GET['activated'] ) && $pagenow == "themes.php" ) {
    $role = get_role( 'author' );
    $role->add_cap( 'edit_others_posts' );
}
```